# Switching methods for a single result

Tags: php, code-formatting

I have a situation where I require to consult different objects in PHP via different methods to find some data.

The question regards more about formatting the code than an actual programming issue. What I am trying to do is not using several `if`'s to gather this data like:

```
$data = obj->getData();
if (!isset($data)) $data = othObj->getThisData();
if (!isset($data)) $data = anothObj->getTheData();
if (!isset($data)) $data = anothOne->getAData();
...
process($data)
```

I was wondering what are the best practices in this case, if there is a better way using another procedures, like `foreach` or `switch/case`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an array of the possible objects you want to try, then run a loop. Might be more maintainable. This code can be modified to include parameters and use call_user_func_array instead.

```
$dataCallback = array(
    array($othObj, 'getData'),
    array($othObj, 'getThisData'),
    array($anothObj, 'getTheData'),
    array($anothOne, 'getAData'),
);

for($i = 0, $t = count($dataCallback); !isset($data) && $i < $t; $i++) {
  $callback = $dataCallback[$i];
  $data = call_user_func($callback);
}

if (isset($data))
  process($data);
else
  //no valid data returned at all ...
```

Comment: sorry but this is just a mess. i would rather use the code he propose, why to complicate things?

Comment: Id stick with my version and make it a function. $dataCallback[] = array($oneMore, 'method'); $data = get_data($dataCallback); better then maintaining lines of if if if if if if if ... gets confusing if you got enough.

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't look too bad the way it is.
2. It could be a bit more efficient if the if's were nested. e.g.

   ```
    if (!isset($data = othObj->getData()))
    if (!isset($data = othObj->getThisData()))
    if (!isset($data = anothObj->getTheData()))
    $data = anothOne->getAData()))
    // ...
    process($data)
   ```

   Since there are less calls to isset (though they're pretty cheap anyway, so I wouldn't worry about it).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd do something like this:

```
$data = null;

if (isset($obj->getData()) $data = $obj->getData();
else if (isset($othObj->getThisData()) $data = $othObj->getThisData();
else if (isset($anothObj->getTheData()) $data = $anothObj->getTheData();
else if (isset($anothOne->getAData()) $data = $anothOne->getAData();

process($data)
```

This saves processing time if the earlier objects actually return something.  Since it is an elseif setup once it finds data it'll stop processing the other if clauses.

I don't think a switch statement would be appropriate in this case.  Switches tend to be testing the value of one variable (is $a = 1, 2, 3 or 4).

Answer (score 0):

```
($data = $ob1->get()) || ($data = $ob2->get()) || ($data = $ob3->get());
```

Would work, but if you're get function returns an empty array or false or empty string instead of NULL, it's going to continue looking for data...

Comment: you have to rewrite it: ($data = $ob1->get()) || ($data = $ob2->get()) || ($data = $ob3->get());

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably group the objects to ask for data into an array:

```
$objArray = array($obj, $othObj, $anothObj, ... );
```

Then run through a while loop until I had data:

```
$i = 0;
do {
   $data = $objArray[$i]->getData();
   $i++;
} while(!isset($data) && $i < count($objArray));
```